# Hibernate Criteria query to find the last but one row for the given empid

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I need to get the last but one record for the user (Requisition id is unique) and I am passing the Employee id to get the record.

Here's what I tried :

```
Requisition r = new Requisition();
session=super.getSession();
Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
Criteria q = session.createCriteria(Requisition.class);

q.setMaxResults(1);
r = (Requisition)q.uniqueResult();
```

Could someone please help me find the error?

Comment: Your query implies that you have a specific _order_ in mind.  So, what is the ordering you want to apply to the query?  Can you give us a raw SQL query?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen                                                                                 Let me give an example : there are many entries for each employee. When I log in as particular employee(empid-12345) I want to update the Date for the last but one record for that employee. But , in my case the second row gets updated in the DB.                                     'SELECT * FROM requisitions where Emp_ID=12345 order by Requisition_ID DESC LIMIT 1,1 ;'

Comment: Why not use `LIMIT 2` and then just keep the second record?

Comment: This code works fine in sql query. But I need the same in criteria. So I wrote like this                                                                     q.setFirstResult(1);                                                        q.setMaxResults(1); and the output is not the same. It always returns the second record from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ok, let me answer the above question :

Hope this helps somebody:

`session=super.getSession();`

`Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();`

`Criteria q = session.createCriteria(Requisition.class);`

`q.setFirstResult(1);`

`q.setMaxResults(1);`

`q.add(Restrictions.eq("empID", empid));`

`q.addOrder( Order.desc("reqID") );`

`r = (Requisition)q.uniqueResult();`